# cocos2d-x's game, when switch from background to foreground on android, why the sprite is black

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have a game coding by cocos2d-x, it run well on iphone, but there is some wrong on android.
I played the game for a while, and then press the 'home' button let it pause(changed to background). However, when I start the game again, can't load the resources or the resources load incomplete, and there some black scene.
someone can help me how to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

When the activity switch to the background. Do not clear the texture cache.

More detail:
http://novacreo.com/%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E7%BB%84/%E8%BF%94%E5%9B%9Eandroid%E6%B8%B8%E6%88%8F%E9%BB%91%E5%B1%8F%E8%A7%A3%E5%86%B3%E5%8A%9E%E6%B3%95/